# How do I change IE script debugger from MS Script Debugger to VS 2005

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2005, debugging

I have Microsoft Script debugger installed and selected (somwhere) as the script debugger of IE. I want to make VS the default script debugger. When I uninstall MS Script debugger IE just wouldn't start any debugger on a javascript error.

So how do I go back to VS as my default IE script debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer in [this blogpost](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/7403.aspx).

So to get VS back as your default debugger you have to open Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Just In time in VS and check 'Script'.